# I am getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" in Capturescreensot method and in Custom Listeners

Tags: selenium

```
**java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.arc.util.TestUtils.captureScreenshot(TestUtils.java:24)
    at com.arc.listeners.CustomListeners.onTestFailure(CustomListeners.java:57)**
```

Here the error is with the below function:
public static void captureScreenshot() throws IOException, WebDriverException {

```
    File src=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    Date d=new Date();
    scereenshotname=d.toString().replaceAll(" ","_").replaceAll(":", "_")+".jpg";
    FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\target\\surefire-reports\\html\\"+scereenshotname));
}
```

Error is coming at File src initialization. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Second problem is with this custome listerners class:

Comment: public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.setProperty("org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output", "fasle");
  Reporter.log(result.getName()+" Test Case failed");
  try {
   TestUtils.captureScreenshot()---> Here also error is coming